# ¿Cómo guardar un archivo PDF en una carpeta del servidos FTP en PHP?

Tags: php, phpmailer, html2pdf

Mis objetivos son los siguientes:

Crear un PDF en base a datos dados mediante un formulario [LISTO]

Guardar este PDF en una carpeta del FTP [NO LOGRADO]

Enviar ese PDF vía email [LISTO]

```
    // init HTML2PDF
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'LETTER', 'es', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
    // display the full page
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    // convert
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    // send the PDF
    $doc = $html2pdf->Output('Pedido_#'.$numero_pedido.'.pdf', 'S');

    require_once ("../../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->From = 'kevinpenatic@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = ''.$rw_perfil['nombre_comercial'].'';
    $mail->Subject = 'Orden de Compra Nº'.$numero_pedido.'';
    $mail->Body = 'Hello '.$rw_proveedor['nombre_proveedor'].', the purchase order is attached, thanks for your services. ';
    $mail->AddAddress('kdpp2000@gmail.com');


    $mail->AddStringAttachment($doc, 'Pedido #'.$numero_pedido.'.pdf', 'base64');
    $mail->send();
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, este código está en una carpeta con esta Dirección:

Orden_De_Compras/Login/Admin/pedidos/pdf/documentos/pedido_pdf.php

Yo deseo que el PDF en el momento justo en el que se cree, se almacene en la siguiente dirección:
 Orden_De_Compras/Login/Admin/OrdenDeCompras/pdf

**Entonces el problema es; ¿qué código es el que me funcionaría para esta acción?**

Comment: ¿Estas queriendo guardar el archivo en el servidor local o queriendo conectarte a un servidor remoto con usuario y contraseña? ¿Estas usando Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el código

```
file_put_contents("../../../nombre_archivo", $contenido_archivo);
```

Donde los

> ../

significan salir al directorio del nivel anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Para crea el archivo:

```
$NombreArchivo = 'Pedido_#'.$numero_pedido.'.pdf';
$doc = $html2pdf->Output($NombreArchivo, 'F');
```

Y para mandarlo como attachment

```
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/'.$NombreArchivo, $NombreArchivo);
```